# `/lib/firmware/BCM43430A1.hcd` owned by non-root user

Tags: permissions, raspberry-pi, firmware, ubuntu-mate

### Description

During an installation, I was hinted that `/lib`'s group isn't `root`. That of course doesn't sound right and as it turned out, it's even worse: The owner of `/lib` isn't `root`, either.

Upon investigating, I found found that it seems to be due to a single file:

```
christoph@christoph-pi:~$ ll / | grep christoph
drwxrwxr-x  23 christoph christoph       4096 Dec  8 16:30 lib/
christoph@christoph-pi:~$ ll /lib | grep christoph
drwxrwxr-x 23 christoph christoph  4096 Dec  8 16:30 ./
drwxrwxr-x 71 christoph christoph 36864 Dec 14 22:52 firmware/
christoph@christoph-pi:~$ ll /lib/firmware/ | grep christoph
drwxrwxr-x 71 christoph christoph   36864 Dec 14 22:52 ./
drwxrwxr-x 23 christoph christoph    4096 Dec  8 16:30 ../
-rw-rw-r--  1 christoph christoph   35976 Feb 27  2016 BCM43430A1.hcd
christoph@christoph-pi:~$ ll /lib/firmware/BCM43430A1.hcd | grep christoph
-rw-rw-r-- 1 christoph christoph 35976 Feb 27  2016 /lib/firmware/BCM43430A1.hcd
```

`christoph` is the first user and the only regular one (regular one = trough which people commonly log in to, not users like `messagebus`, `nobody`, or `root`) which was created during installation of the OS. It also is the only sudoer.

As you probably already guessed from the host name, it's a Raspberry Pi. A Raspberry Pi 3, to be precise, and it runs Ubuntu 16.04 Mate. However, it used to run a previous version of Ubuntu Mate. In 2016, I upgraded that installation to 16.04. The previous version was either 15.04 or 15.10 (I'm pretty confident it was 15.10 but am not entirely sure).

### My Questions

1. How could it have happened that a non-root user is the owner of `/lib`?
2. Is it safe to make `root` the user and group of `/lib`, `/lib/firmware`, and `/lib/firmware/BCM43430A1.hcd`? Could this stop something from working properly or at all?